# Java Convention return type

Tags: java, coding-style

I want to ask which implementation is better. I think the first method is better because when I read this method, I know this method return personId, it's more readable than the second one. is it right?

Method 1:

```
public String persistPerson(Person person) {
    String personId = persistService.persist(person);
    return personId;
}
```

Method 2:

```
public String persistPerson(Person person) {
    return persistService.persist(person);
}
```

Comment: You may consider having a javadoc block on your method, explaining what it returns.

Comment: self documenting code is good, but javadocs as well is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every con has two sides so as your program because both the defination has one advantage over other.

**For 1st method:-**

- **Advantage:** : It is more readable as the other person comes to understand very quickly that what it returns.
- **Disadvantage :** :- As you formulate a new string it will use some space to create new string so wastage of memory.

**For 2nd method:-**

- **Advantage :-** It avoids wastage of memory.
- **Disadvantage :-** Its not readable

Answer (score 1):

The first method is pretty readable. You could split it up into two small setter and getter methods if you want to make it even easier to understand. 
I would suggest you use javadocs to document your code if your intention is to later explain what everything does.

Answer (score -1):

The first way is really better. When other guys look at this code, they immediately know what is the returned value. In contrast they must read java doc to know what is returned in the second way.